# Internet Explorer not displaying img in liferay environment

Tags: image, spring-mvc, internet-explorer, liferay, http-status-code-304

I am literally going crazy about this issue.

We have set up a Liferay environment that is using @RessourceMapping Methods to provide Images to our website. Those images show up on every browser (Safari, Chrome, Firefox, Mobile)- except Internet Explorer.

Our Code in the backend is pretty straightforward:

```
public void getImage(ResourceRequest request, ResourceResponse response) throws IOException {

byte[] imageSrc = getImageFromDatabase()
response.setContentType("image/jpg");
OutputStream portletOutputStream = response.getPortletOutputStream();
portletOutputStream.write(imageSrc);
response.setContentLength(length);
portletOutputStream.flush();
portletOutputStream.close();

}
```

The JSP displaying the Image is also not complicated:

```
<div class="span12">
    <img src="${getImageUrl}" width="100%" />
</div>
```

What I can see (In Internet Explorer Dev Tools) is that for some of the pictures that don´t get loaded I do get a 304 and for others just "cancelled".

Here is an example of the URL I am calling :

```
http://my-server/web/my-portlet/display?p_p_id=mylongportletnamedisplayportlet_WAR_mylongportletname&p_p_lifecycle=2&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_resource_id=getImage&p_p_cacheability=cacheLevelPage&p_p_col_id=column2&p_p_col_count=2&_mylongportletnamedisplayportlet_WAR_mylongportletname_id=658468&_mylongportletnamedisplayportlet_WAR_mylongportletname_imageType=logo&_mylongportletnamedisplayportlet_WAR_mylongportletname_entityType=car
```

Any idea why those images are not displayed in Internet Explorer ?

Comment: Can you share the `getImageUrl` as well the image link being generated?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. The image is just a normal jpg / RGB image. Nothing Special here. The URL I will paste above

Comment: There is nothing in the URL which identifies image content. Its just the AJAX call URL. Shouldn't you write image somewhere and set it's link to img tag?

Comment: I'd like to see the HTTP level traffic on this. Can you "view image" and see what you get there? Or check with whatever Firebug-like debug-tool IE supports.

Comment: Hi Everyone. I have no idea why this happend but what I did was to replace the RessourceMapping with a Servlet and everything works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found an answer to my question but I have found a workaround:

I am using a simple servlet now. It just returns the Image and that´s it: Done in 5 mins, works like a charm.

I will stick with servlets for now.